# VB to VC# Class Conversion - Going Brain Dead

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, properties

I am taking a little trip down memory loss lane and find myself at an impasse with a small bit of code. Been researching it all week and nothing has popped up to explain what I am doing wrong. I am trying to convert it to C#. The original VB code is -

```
Public Class CustomFormData

    Private ReadOnly Context As System.Web.HttpContext
    Private ReadOnly l_QSItems As New System.Collections.ArrayList

    Private ReadOnly Property CookieName() As String
        Get
            Return "EmberCookie"
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property MaxStringSize() As Integer
        Get
            Return 10
        End Get
    End Property

    Default Protected Property Item(ByVal index As enu.QS) As String
        Get
            Try
                Return l_QSItems.Item(index).ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ""
            End Try
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            ValidateStringSize(index.ToString, Value)
            l_QSItems.Item(index) = Value
            SaveCookie(index, Value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub ValidateStringSize(ByVal [name] As String, ByVal value As String)
        If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso value.Length > Me.MaxStringSize Then
            Throw New System.Security.SecurityException( _
                String.Format("{0} contains value larger than allowed length of {1}.  Size was {2} char(s).", [name], Me.MaxStringSize, value.Length))
        End If
    End Sub
```

What I have accomplish thus far is -

```
    class CustomFormData
    {
        private readonly System.Collections.ArrayList l_QSItems = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        private readonly int MaxStringSize
        {
            get
            {
               return 10;
            }
        }
        protected string Item(enu.QS index) 
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return Item(index).ToString();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            set (string Value)
            {
                ValidateStringSize(index.ToString(), Value);
                l_QSItems.Item(index) == Value;
            }
        }

        private string ValidateStringSize(string[] name, string value)
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length > MaxStringSize)
            {
                throw new System.Security.SecurityException(string.Format("{0} contains value larger than allowed length of {1}.  Size was {2} char(s).", name, MaxStringSize, value.Length));
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting in several errors-

```
Error   1   } expected  c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   31  14  EMBER-Win
Error   2   Method must have a return type  c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   32  13  EMBER-Win
Error   3   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   39  17  EMBER-Win
Error   4   Identifier expected c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   39  50  EMBER-Win
Error   5   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   39  52  EMBER-Win
Error   6   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   43  27  EMBER-Win
Error   7   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   45  13  EMBER-Win
Error   8   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   49  9   EMBER-Win
Error   9   ; expected  c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   21  16  EMBER-Win
Error   10  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   21  13  EMBER-Win
Error   11  The name 'get' does not exist in the current context    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   21  13  EMBER-Win
Error   12  The name 'ValidateStringSize' does not exist in the current context c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   34  17  EMBER-Win
Error   13  The name 'index' does not exist in the current context  c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   34  36  EMBER-Win
Error   14  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   35  17  EMBER-Win
Error   15  'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   35  27  EMBER-Win
Error   16  The name 'index' does not exist in the current context  c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   35  32  EMBER-Win
Error   17  The type or namespace name '?Attribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   39  49  EMBER-Win
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. If you have knowledge of a periodical or website that focuses on VB to VC# conversions, that would be very helpful. Many of my technical manuals have not found their way back to my cube over the years so I am missing my source information for C#.

Thank you my friends, have a pleasant weekend.

:D

Based upon recommendations, this is where it stands now -

```
class CustomFormData
{
    private readonly System.Collections.ArrayList l_QSItems = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    private readonly int MaxStringSize
    {
        get
        {
           return 10;
        }
    }
    protected string this[enu.QS index] 
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return l_QSItems[index].ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateStringSize(index.ToString(), value);
            l_QSItems[index] = value;
        }
    }
```

I have this error:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ArrayList.this[int]' has some invalid arguments    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   25  28  EMBER-Win
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'enu.QS' to 'int'   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   25  38  EMBER-Win
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ArrayList.this[int]' has some invalid arguments    c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   35  17  EMBER-Win
Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'enu.QS' to 'int'   c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs   35  27  EMBER-Win
```

For those folks that have submitted code, here is a piece I left out.

```
public enum QS
{
    //'For Policy
    policy_class,
    fiscal_ref_id,
    cycle_fy,
    cycle_month,
    policy_version,
    policyReadOnly,

    //'For Base Estimate
    mode_code,
    dvar_id,
    node_id,
    aids_code,
    county_code,
    care_code,
    plan_code,
    ffs_code,
    service_code,
    errorOnly,
    additional_actuals_month_id,

    //'For policy change search
    search_cycle_version,
    search_analyst_id,
    search_category_code,
    search_change_number,
    search_fiscal_ref,
    secondary_sort,
    sort_descending,

    //'To identify the BO narrative report layout for selected policy
    narrative_option,

    //'To identify version selected for Federal spread
    selected_version
};
```

Thanks again for the assist.

Comment: Did you try running it thru a converter ?

Comment: An indexer in C# uses square brackets not parens

Comment: As @EdPlunkett mentionned, I'd look up how to make indexers in C#, this is where most of your errors seem to be coming from

Comment: Popo, Ed, well gentlemen, there is truth in "it takes a village". Both of your comments have provided the info I needed to get past this. Thank you for greasing the wheels of this ancient brain. Kudos to you both.

Comment: Ed - Seems like this issue would make a great article for Converting VB classes to C# classes. The particular program I am working on was written in 2002 for Web Apps, and I am converting it to a WinForm project due to certain operational constraints and new customer requirements. Several of the idiosyncratic aspects of VB  are coming to light as I move through each class module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexer has a few problems.

In C#, we use square brackets, and the "this" indexer is `this`, not `Item`. The `set` never gets an explicit parameter; that's implicitly defined and it's always `value`, all lowercase. C# is case sensitive.

Also, you used `==` for an assignment. In C#, as in C, double equals is for comparison and single equals is for assignment.

I don't quite know what to make of this in the `Item` `get`:

```
return Item(index).ToString();
```

That looks infinitely recursive to me. Is that what the catch is for? (j/k) Or should it have been `l_QSItems.Item(index).ToString()`? I'm going to assume the latter. It would make sense if this is just a validating wrapper indexer for the private field.

```
public class CustomFormData
{
    private System.Web.HttpContext Context;

    private String CookieName
    {
        get { return "EmberCookie"; }
    }

    private readonly System.Collections.ArrayList l_QSItems
        //  Initialize with enough nulls to accomodate the largest enum value as an index.
        = new System.Collections.ArrayList(new object[(int)enu.QS.additional_actuals_month_id + 1]);

    //  readonly modifier not allowed here. Not needed either. 
    //  Same as on CookieName
    private int MaxStringSize
    {
        get
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    protected string this[enu.QS index]
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                //  index is an enum. It won't implicitly cast to int as in 
                //  C/C++ (or, I infer, VB.NET), but an explicit cast is fine. 
                return l_QSItems[(int)index].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateStringSize(index.ToString(), value);
            l_QSItems[(int)index] = value;
        }
    }

    //  name[] would be an array of strings, we only want just one string. 
    private void ValidateStringSize(string name, string value)
    {
        if (value != null && value.Length > this.MaxStringSize)
        {
            throw new System.Security.SecurityException(string.Format("{0} contains value larger than allowed length of {1}.  Size was {2} char(s).", name, this.MaxStringSize, value.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

This is also problematic:

```
private string ValidateStringSize(string[] name, string value)
```

`string[]` is an array of strings; a single string is just `string`. It's clear from usage and from the body of the method itself that `name` should be one string, not an array:

```
private string ValidateStringSize(string name, string value)
```

Were you exposed to C at some point long ago?

Comment: Yes, I did C back in the 80s, mostly embedded.

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ArrayList.this[int]' has some invalid arguments c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs 25 28 EMBER-Win
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'enu.QS' to 'int' c:\Projects\EMBER-Win\EMBER-Win\_common\CustomFormData.cs 25 38 EMBER-Win

Comment: @DarrellRobertParker I'm guessing the VB is implicitly casting the enum to int. I've added an explicit cast which makes the whole thing compile. Popo got there first with removing `readonly` from `MaxStringSize` though.

Comment: @DarrellRobertParker See final (I hope) update. I was getting exceptions assinging to arbitrary indexes in an ArrayList so I added a fix for that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett VB does do an implicit conversion on enums to Int, I just gave it a test. :)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from not having a enu.QS type or the SaveCookie method, this compiles. Maybe its helpful.

```
using System;

public class CustomFormData
{

    private readonly System.Web.HttpContext Context;

    private readonly System.Collections.ArrayList l_QSItems = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    private string CookieName
    {
        get { return "EmberCookie"; }
    }

    private int MaxStringSize
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }

    protected string this[enu.QS index]
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return l_QSItems[Convert.ToInt32(index)].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateStringSize(index.ToString(), value);
            l_QSItems[Convert.ToInt32(index)] = value;
            SaveCookie(index, value);
        }
    }



    private void ValidateStringSize(string name, string value)
    {
        if (value != null && value.Length > this.MaxStringSize)
        {
            throw new System.Security.SecurityException(string.Format("{0} contains value larger than allowed length of {1}.  Size was {2} char(s).", name, this.MaxStringSize, value.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public enum QS
    {
        //'For Policy
        policy_class,
        fiscal_ref_id,
        cycle_fy,
        cycle_month,
        policy_version,
        policyReadOnly,

        //'For Base Estimate
        mode_code,
        dvar_id,
        node_id,
        aids_code,
        county_code,
        care_code,
        plan_code,
        ffs_code,
        service_code,
        errorOnly,
        additional_actuals_month_id,

        
    };

Comment: I was going to suggest `Convert.ToInt32(index)` but I see it was already mentioned. I updated my answer none the less.

Comment: I will also mention that it could cause problems down the road if someone rearranged the members in the enum, it would be best to explicitly assign the values.